# How to hide label when undefined/empty/null

Tags: reactjs, charts

I'm using react-chartjs-2 to create the charts. Each alphabet letter has is a chart label but in the beginning and during somebody plays around with the chart some of the labels will be empty/undefined. I want to hide the labels that are undefined until somebody adds something to that label. I can't figure out a way to do it hence the `options` can't be inside the `data`. If anyone has an idea how to hide them, please help me out.

```js
    let alphabet = ['B','C','D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];

    const data = {
      labels: [...this.state.rows.map(x => x.A)],
      datasets: alphabet.map(value => {
        let color = this.state.color[value] || this.state.color.DEFAULT,
        checkIfUndefined = () => {
          if (this.state.rows[0][value] === undefined) {
            return false
          } return this.state.rows[0][value];
        }
      return{
        label: checkIfUndefined(),
        data: this.state.rows.map(x => x[value]),
        backgroundColor: `rgba(${color.r}, ${color.g}, ${color.b}, ${color.a})`,
      }}),
    };

    let options = {
      legend: {
        display: true,
      }
    }

    <Line 
      data={data}
      options={options}
    />
```